# i'm using nest js and mongodb with prisma and i want to add three collection in how can i do?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, nestjs, prisma

i want to add three model of prisma just like.
schema.prisma

```
model women{
id  string @id @default(auto()) @map("_id") @db.ObjectId
womenname: string;
womengender: string
womendob: string
womenincome: string
}
model men{
id  string @id @default(auto()) @map("_id") @db.ObjectId
malename: string;
malegender: string
maledob: string
maleincome: string
}
model child{
id  string @id @default(auto()) @map("_id") @db.ObjectId
childname: string;
childgender: string
childdob: string
}
```

how can i add this three model in one model. just Like this.

```
model information{
male: //male model data,
women: // women model data,
child: //child model data
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That's already described in the documentation of Prisma, you have two options

- Use the composite types so you have separate documents for each entity and you can access them by the parent model like users.tasks

```js
model User {
  id     String  @id @default(auto()) @map("_id") @db.ObjectId
  tasks  Task[]
}

model Task {
  id              String   @id @default(auto()) @map("_id") @db.ObjectId
  user            Product  @relation(fields: [userId], references: [id])
  userId          String   @db.ObjectId
}
```

- Or if you just want to have the interface (a type that defines the attributes that a property in your collection can have) you can just define a custom type like the following, taking the same example of the user and the tasks

```js
model User {
  id   String @id @default(auto()) @map("_id") @db.ObjectId
  tasks Task[]
}

// This will not be a different collection but it will work as "rules" or schema for the attributes inside the user.tasks property

type Task {
  title       String
  description String
}
```

With this last example you will have something like this

```json
// users document
{
  "_id": "SOME RANDOM ID",
  "tasks": [
    {
      "title": "SOME TITLE",
      "description": "SOME DESCRIPTION"
    }

  ]
}
```

You can also try to take a deeper look at the documentation here https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-client/composite-types

I hope it has been helpful.